# Review my question: Is it violating any Stack Overflow rules?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, not-constructive

I have a perfectly valid [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451087/gps-to-googlemap-and-other-tools-like-distance-and-radius). A user believes that the question is invalid. I strongly believe otherwise. I request meta to review the question, and if it's invalid, I will gladly remove it. I strongly believe that Stack Overflow should be kept clean and useful. It is the best website for Q&A, and I don't want to be the one to violate its rules.

Comment: Well, it appears to apply with the faq, but it's sort of hard to understand exactly what you want? Do you need a tool to do something? Do you want to know something about a tool?

Comment: There are websites that make your css code look good. They add indents to the code. I need a website that helps me locate on the map with gps coordinates, and provides gps coordinates with markers on the map. And other features. I have provided a good example website that I use. What I need is clear.

Comment: Well, then. It appears your question is perfectly within the scope.

Comment: I would close that question (as I have voted to do so) as not constructive. We are not a shopping list site, and do not like questions that ask us for tools, as tools tend to break over time.

Comment: How does the question relate to a shopping list ? Making a generic statement like "tools tend to break over time" is extremely loose. Stackoverflow is a tool for Q&A, are you saying that Stackoverflow is a tool that will break over time, and hence should not be encouraged ? Asking the question is within the boundary of the FAQ, and that is the only thing that matters, not a personal opinion which has no data/justification.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Your comment should really be an answer, in my opinion. It's better than the recommendation to look for another SE site and the voting it would get would demonstrate it's not just *"a personal opinion which has no data/justification"* but simply the "common opinion" on which is built SO.

Comment: @Siddharth The faq isn't the law. The faq helps understand what is SO and what SO users wants it to be. Being "within the boundary of the FAQ" here only means the FAQ isn't perfectly clear (it couldn't be).

Comment: You argument doesnt make sense. Tools do break over time, that is a reality. That in no way means, that tools that could break tomorrow, should not be used today. If the world shifts to gesture control in the future, would you make people throw away their keyboards and mouse now ?!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine. Your question is not constructive. It is that simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That question really belongs on another site - it isn't really related to programming, and is asking for a product, not how to code something.

Try looking through the [SE site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites), and see if one of them is a better fit.

Comment: There are so many more questions that ask for tools. Are you going to flag them all ? Stackoverflow is the common location for common kinda questions related to programming. And tools that help you debug while programming. Off-topic is just so not correct for this question.

Comment: Well, to be fair, it does state "software tools commonly used by programmers" in the faq.

Comment: Yes, making it off topic is just so incorrect for this question. And none of the other stackoverflow sites address this kinda question. @Riking when you recommended that I go thru the list, did you find anything in particular that you believe that my question fits in ? Or was it a generic suggestion ?

Comment: @ProfPickle that is a very common misinterpretation of that line in the FAQ. This is in essence a recommendation question. And even for "software tools commonly used by programmers" those are off-topic.

Comment: @Bart Should that particular section of the faq be remodeled to combat the common misinterpretation?

Comment: @ProfPickle I'd say the misinterpretation is the result of selective reading of the faq. But you could propose something else if you have an idea. See if there is not a duplicate request first though.

Comment: @Bart Just re-read the whole (relevant) section of the FAQ, and I see the problem. It says that asking questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers", but it doesn't talk about what aspect (although it does have dos and don'ts). I might raise a question tomorrow as I'm pretty tired and can't put too much effort into it.

Comment: @Siddharth to answer your first comment... all questions that ask "Is there a tool that does X" should be flagged and/or closed.  Most you have found that a still open are older when the rules on this were more lax, and the rest are probably newer questions that just slipped by without getting noticed.  The simple fact is the presence of a specific question does not mean it is on-topic, but could just mean that it has not been closed yet.